# cvs update error

Tags: cvs

I am using WinCVS and when i try to update a module i keep getting this error

cvs [update aborted]: reading from server: error -1

What is the actual problem here and how to resolve this?

Comment: Are you using a pserver-style connection, ssh tunneling, or something else? Is the repository on your computer, another computer internal to your network, or across the Internet? (If it's not your computer, does it run Windows or another OS?) Have any recent network topology changes been made? Can you still do a fresh checkout from the server?

Comment: Like Arthur, I think more details would be useful... Can you access the same repository from a different machine ? Can you try from a linux command line (you may be able to get more information about the error) ?

Comment: its a pserver style connection. The repository is across the internet and the server is running RedHat Linux. I am not sure if any network topology has changed. I can checkout and commit , only the update fails.

Answer (score 1):

I had this and similar problems, resolved by trying variations on my CVSROOT pserver string, to include username@hostname/cvs. Also cvs logout then login again.
Don't know exactly why it worked since they should be equivalent.

Comment: So did this produce any result ? As I say, I had just the same issue which the above 'twiddling' resolved.

Comment: The cvs logout worked for me.  Previously I had reinstalled TortoiseCVS plus the CVS client independently and rebooted multiple times.  No result.  Then I did a "cvs logout" in the console and tried an update.  It asked for the password and then it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Your anti-virus/firewall may be the problem here.
Disable/Uninstall them and try again.

Comment: I tried disabling the firewall for wincvs. When i try to update now i still get the error cvs [update aborted]: writing to server socket: error -1

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link which gives description for errors found for cvs. Check if this helps you in resolving your issue -

http://www.thathost.com/wincvs-howto/cvsdoc/cvs_21.html

Comment: The error descriptions aren't useful, since they don't include "reading from".  The troubleshooting tips might be useful, but since the OP didn't bother answering the question about access method we can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do a whole checkout but no update?

I had the same error at work and it puzzlingly was a problem related with access rights on the server. To know whether you have the same problem, ask a colleague to try with his own login.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen strange problems depending on the CVS client/server version when the compression was turned *off*. The solution to many of our problems was to use compression (lowest setting would suffice), even though on the LAN this would not have been a neccessity. Not sure anymore what the message was, but maybe this helps you.