# Checking out folder from CVS via command prompt

Tags: command-line-arguments, command-prompt, cvs

My current command looks like this:

```
cvs -d ":sspi:$User@$Server:2401:/$Company/lib/dotnet/$Folder" checkout
```

I only receive the error message "cvs [checkout aborted]: Error reading from server $Server: -1: Unknown error.

All variables with a $ have of course been censored. Can anyone tell me what's missing in there?

Comment: Could it be that you need `$(User)` and `$(Server)`.  It might depend on the shell.

Comment: Is that the exact error message (ie, it says `from server $Server`, and not `from server myserver.something.com`)?

Comment: Tried using $(User) and $(Server) but it doesn't work. It's the original message.

Comment: Can you check my other comment and confirm?

Comment: Did just that, I'm not used to comment on stackoverflow. Didn't know pressing Enter would send the comment ...

Comment: Ok, but the error message you're getting, does it exactly say `server $Server`?

Comment: It does of course say cvs [checkout aborted]: Error reading from server ActualServername: -1: Unknown error

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582499/cvs-update-error

Comment: I don't think you want that last `:` after the port number 2401. Try removing it.